# Why/how does dynamic work with generics?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

**tl;dr** How does `dynamic` work going into a method taking a `IQueryable<T>` generic?  And why does it then not work trying to use methods available to `IQueryable<T>` directly against the `dynamic` instance?

For a quick background, I was working on a test project to check our Entity Framework context against a database, to be better prepared whenever we move environments.  I initially came up with this simple test just to see if the entity would load according to the existing schema:

```
private static bool CheckSchema<T>(IQueryable<T> dbSet)
{
    try
    {
        dbSet.FirstOrDefault();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private async void TestSchemaButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LayoutRoot.IsEnabled = false;
    ResultsPane.Text = "";

    var cStrings = LoadEnvironmentConnectionStrings();
    var results = new StringBuilder();

    ResultsPane.Text += "--- Testing " + nameof(MyProject.MyDbContext1) + "...";
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var db = new MyProject.MyDbContext1())
        {
            db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = cStrings.Item1;

            if (!CheckSchema(db.MyDbSetProperty1)) results.AppendLine(nameof(MyProject.MyDbContext1.MyDbSetProperty1) + " has invalid schema.");
            // ...
            if (!CheckSchema(db.MyDbSetPropertyN)) results.AppendLine(nameof(MyProject.MyDbContext1.MyDbSetPropertyN) + " has invalid schema.");
        }
    });
    ResultsPane.Text += Environment.NewLine + results.ToString() + 
                        "--- End " + nameof(MyProject.MyDbContext1) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

This is pretty simple, and accomplished what I was after.  However, I have multiple DB contexts to test, some with many, many entities.  I'm a programmer, so I'm of course lazy, and even though it's mostly copy-paste, there's still a lot of renaming to do.  Since performance wasn't a concern for this manually-run, test project, I figured I could just get all the entities to test via reflection.

It was at this point I became initially stuck, since I needed my property to be an `IQueryable<T>`, but I have no idea how to cast when a generic is involved.  I realized I could cheat a bit by using `dynamic` and thus my `Task` body could become:

```
using (var db = new MyProject.MyDbContext1())
{
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    var dbSetProps = db.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.Name == "DbSet`1");

    foreach (var dbSetProp in dbSetProps)
    {
        dynamic dbSetVal = dbSetProp.GetValue(db);
        if (!CheckSchema(dbSetVal))
            results.AppendLine(dbSetProp.Name + " has invalid schema.");
    }
}
```

I was pleasantly surprised to find that this simply worked.  What I don't get is how?  I figured that even as versatile as generics can be, they are still a compile-time construct.

Additionally, I figured that I could change my whole `CheckSchema` method to do all the work that was in the body of the `Task`, so I updated as so:

```
private static string CheckSchema<T>(string connectionString) where T : DbContext, new()
{
    var invalidSchemas = new StringBuilder();
    using (var db = new T())
    {
        db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        var dbSetProps = db.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.Name == "DbSet`1");

        foreach (var dbSetProp in dbSetProps)
        {
            dynamic dbSetVal = dbSetProp.GetValue(db);
            try
            {
                dbSetVal.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch
            {
                invalidSchemas.AppendLine(dbSetProp.Name + " has invalid schema.");
            }
        }
    }
    return invalidSchemas.ToString();
}
```

But now it always encounters an exception at `dbSetVal.FirstOrDefault()` saying that "`DbSet<MyProject.MyDbContext1.MyDbSetPropertyNEntityType>` does not contain a method `FirstOrDefault`."  I'm fine going back to my second implementation, as it is still pretty compact.  However, it's got me wondering, what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dynamic` essentially tells the compiler to bypass static checks. This means that all binding must be done at run-time, not at compile time.

```
IQueryable<Person> people = GetPeople();
dynamic dPerson = people;
```

Here, `dPerson` is *still* an `IQueryable<Person>`, but we've specifically asked the compiler not to create any compile-time assumptions about it. If one were to write `dPerson.ToString()`, the method `ToString` would only be resolved *as it's being called*.

The consequence of this is, that you lose the syntactic sugar of extension methods. Writing the following:

`people.FirstOrDefault()` is *actually* writing `Queryable.FirstOrDefault(people);`

You cannot use extension methods on `dynamic` objects. At runtime, it will look for the method `FirstOrDefault` on the object itself, and will not check for possible extension methods.

You need to write, instead, `Queryable.FirstOrDefault(dbSetVal);`

Comment: Can't you call extension methods of `object` on dynamic instances?

Comment: @phoog Nope, you can't.

Comment: Well I just tried a little prototype with no problem.  You can't declare an extension method on dynamic, but you can declare one on object and call it on a dynamic variable.

Comment: @phoog Are you sure about that? Can you show me the code where you are successfully calling an extension method on an object cast as `dynamic` ?

Comment: well apparently Resharper rewrote the call into static method syntax and I didn't notice since my prototype used only single letter names.  So I typed `d.M()` and Resharper changed it to `E.M(d)` without my noticing.  So no, I can't show you where I did that, because I didn't. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest forget the dynamic and work with reflection. You neet to call `dbContext.Set<xx>()` for each entity type you have got by reflection, so assuming you have an entity type in the variable "entityType":

```
//this should be done outside the loop of entity types
var setMethodInfo = db.GetType().GetMethod("Set");
//build the Set method info for the current type
var setEntityTypeMI = setMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
//Execute
var dbSetToTest = setEntityTypeMI.Invoke(db, null);
```

Now you can call your test method with the DbSet<> instance.

I couldn't test it but should work

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: But @Enigmativity he started with dynamic because was unable to do this... It s wrong to solve the real problem?? I don't think so, but if you enjoy down voting have fun

Comment: By all means provide a method to solve the underlying issue, but the OP's question was very clear. So you should either answer the question directly and then add the alternative solution **or** you should explicitly say in your first paragraph that you're not directly answering the question. Had you done the former I would have given you an up-vote; the latter I would have left the question alone; otherwise a down-vote is entirely justified.